# Getting an ActiveX warning when I load a page via HTTP that has an HTTPS remote javascript included

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, https

So basically I have a basic page that is loaded via http.

Inside this application I want to include a remotely hosted JS file. Currently when I load the page I always have the active X warning about security. I pretty much tried every possible way to include th Javascript file (jquery.getScript, creating a node programmatically, escaping characters and all that stuff).

The JS file itself is on a domain that is on HTTPS but that the certificate is not valid (pointing somewhere else apparently). (It's our QA server). I do not have access on the server and therefore am not able to modify anything server side.

If I click on the warning and select "Display blocked content" the JS file is still not loaded.

The warning bar itself says :

> To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has blocked this
>   website from displaying content with security certificate error. Click
>   here for options...

Options are :

- Display blocked content
- What's the risk ?
- Information bar help

If I go to the javascript file itself I have this warning :

> There is a problem with this website's security certificate.
>
> ```
>  The security certificate presented by this website was issued for
> ```
>
> a different website's address.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or
>   intercept any data you send to the server.     We recommend that you
>   close this webpage and do not continue to this website.     Click here
>   to close this webpage.     Continue to this website (not recommended).

Is there a way to make a workaround  ?

Comment: If the JS file is static (not dynamically generated), you could bypass the problem by keeping a local copy, removing the need to fetch it from the remote ("bad") server.

Comment: @SLaks I've edited the question with more details

Comment: @Marc-B I require to make a remote call, since the JS basically tokenize some CC info for PCI compliance

Comment: You can tell IE to trust the certificate. Load up the JS file's URl directly in the address bar, then do the override while loading the page. That should make the override permanent for that browser install and let your regular page work.

Comment: @Marc-B thanks for the answer, unfortunally it does not seems to work. If I click "Continue to this website (not recommended)." It prompts me to download the JS file but when I come back to the page, I have the same problem.

Comment: there should be an option in there to accept/force the cert  to be treated as valid. maybe it can be done from the internet options -> content -> certificates section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message: "*The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address*" means that the URL/hostname that you're using to access the site isn't the URL/hostname for which the site has a certificate. If you run Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) with HTTPS-decryption enabled, you'll get a popup alert that explains this mismatch more clearly (specifically, by showing you what Hostname the server is *expecting* you to be using). You can then correct your markup to refer to the site using the correct hostname, which will correct the certificate error and make the problem go away.